# Почему регулярное выражение не правильно разбирает строку?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Добрый день, не могу понять использую для разбора строки данную конструцию

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {

private static String fileName = "photo 20101010  101845   89.1380    59.1533     335386058327798      люрмдшнмдшн.jpg";
private static String data;
private static double data1;



public static void main(String[] arg){ 

    parsingGPS1();
}



public static void parsingGPS1(){
     try {
        String variableName = fileName;
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\s{3}(\\d){1,}.(\\d){1,}\\s{4})"); 
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(variableName); 
        System.out.println("ПРОВЕРКА fileName:" + fileName); 
        System.out.println("ПРОВЕРКА pattern:" + pattern); 
        System.out.println("ПРОВЕРКА matcher:" + matcher); 

       while (matcher.find()) 
       data = matcher.group();
       data1 = Double.parseDouble(data.trim());
       System.out.println("ПРОВЕРКА:" + data); 
     } catch (Exception e){}
   }
}
```

на выходе всегда получал первую координату из строки 89.1380 но в какой то момент регулярное выражении стало выдавать 335386058327798 причём попытки как то исправить его не к чему не приводят. Формат строки не менялся.

Результат работы

> ПРОВЕРКА fileName:photo 20101010  101845   89.1380    59.1533     335386058327798      люрмдшнмдшн.jpg
>   ПРОВЕРКА pattern:(\s{3}(\d){1,}.(\d){1,}\s{4})
>   ПРОВЕРКА matcher:java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=(\s{3}(\d){1,}.(\d){1,}\s{4}) region=0,84 lastmatch=]
>   ПРОВЕРКА:   335386058327798

Теперь выводиться

> ПРОВЕРКА fileName:photo 20161216  102823   89.1380    59.1533     353346056397888       люрмдшнмдшн.jpg
>   ПРОВЕРКА pattern:(\s{3}(\d){1,}.(\d){1,}\s{4})
>   ПРОВЕРКА matcher:java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=(\s{3}(\d){1,}.(\d){1,}\s{4}) region=0,84 lastmatch=]
>   ПРОВЕРКА:   89.1380
>   ПРОВЕРКА:   335386058327798

как это номер 335386058327798 попадает в переменную, регулярка совсем не под него написана ?

Comment: Очень просто -- `.` (точка) в регулярках представляется любым символом, поэтому вам ее нужно экранировать, чтобы она как точка воспринималась, т.е. заменить на `\\.` и должно сработать. А еще, `{1,}` можно заменить на `+`

Comment: Вы опять правы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наверное, код у вас должен был быть такой:

```java
    while (matcher.find()) {
        data = matcher.group();
        data1 = Double.parseDouble(data.trim());
        System.out.println("ПРОВЕРКА:" + data); 
    }
```

Comment: Да верно, но всё ровно не могу понять дополнил вопрос.